# Seleccionar registro a registro en query Codigneter

Tags: codeigniter, sql

Soy nuevo en esto del Codeigneter así que pido disculpas de ante mano:

Tengo definida la siguiente Query:

```
$query=$this->db->select('articulo,descripcion,precio,cant,por_dto1,imp_cos,imp_bru,imp_net');
    $query=$this->db->from('alb_lin'); 
    $query=$this->db->where('empresa',$empresa);        
    $query=$this->db->where('delegacio',$delegacio);
    $query=$this->db->where('ser_alb',$ser_alb);
    $query=$this->db->where('num_alb',$num_alb);
    $query=$this->db->get('');        
    $data["DatosLinea"]=array();

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
      foreach ($query->result() as $fila)
      {            
        $data["DatosLinea"]["articulo"] = $fila->articulo;            
        $data["DatosLinea"]["descripcion"] = $fila->descripcion;
        $data["DatosLinea"]["precio"] = $fila->precio;
        $data["DatosLinea"]["cant"] = $fila->cant;
        $data["DatosLinea"]["por_dto1"] = $fila->por_dto1;
        $data["DatosLinea"]["imp_cos"] = $fila->imp_cos;
        $data["DatosLinea"]["imp_bru"] = $fila->imp_bru;
        $data["DatosLinea"]["imp_net"] = $fila->imp_net;
      }
      return $data["DatosLinea"];
    }
```

Ahora bien, esta query me devuelve más de un registro, pero no se como indicar en la vista que me los muestre uno a uno
ya que tengo puesto lo siguiente

```
    $html = (" ".$VerLinea['articulo']." ");
```

y sólo me muestra el último.
Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que tu Controlador debería quedar así.

```
    $this->db->select('articulo,descripcion,precio,cant,por_dto1,imp_cos,imp_bru,imp_net');
        //$this->db->from('alb_lin'); 
        $$this->db->where('empresa',$empresa);        
        $this->db->where('delegacio',$delegacio);
        $this->db->where('ser_alb',$ser_alb);
        $this->db->where('num_alb',$num_alb);
        $query = $this->db->get('alb_lin');    
        $data['DatosLinea'] =$query->result();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
```

Pon algo así en la vista.

```
<?php if ($DatosLinea): ?>
  <?php foreach ($DatosLinea as $key): ?>
   <?php echo $key->articulo ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por la ayuda pero no me funciona me da el siguiente error:

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Por otro lado la vista la tengo codificada de la siguiente manera:

```
    $DatosLinea = $this->input->post('DatosLinea');        
    $VerLinea = $this->pdfs_model->getLineasSeleccionadas($empresa, $delegacio, $num_alb, $ser_alb);        

    foreach ($VerLinea as $fila)         
    {
        $articulo       = $VerLinea['articulo'];
        $descripcion    = $VerLinea['descripcion'];
        $cant           = $VerLinea['cant'];
        $por_dto1       = $VerLinea['por_dto1'];   
        $imp_cos        = $VerLinea['imp_cos'];   
        $imp_bru        = $VerLinea['imp_bru']; 
        $imp_net        = $VerLinea['imp_net']; 
    }
```

Y lo que comento tanto al hacer el ECHO me salen todos los registros y si lo saco por HTML como os he indicado antes, me sale solo el último.

Comment: ese es tu controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes que revisar bien tu modelo o si no envíalo, pero te doy algunas pautas.

Modelo

```
public function getLineasSeleccionadas($empresa, $delegacio, $num_alb, $ser_alb){
....
return $resultados->result();
}
```

En tu caso debes emplear **result()** a lo mejor estas devolviendo con

```
return $resultado->row();
```

Este último te da solo una línea de registro